# No module named PIL error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, jython

I am making jython project. And I am importing Image from PIL in my python module like:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Though the PIL exists in the python folder and I have even added it in the Libraries of the Python Interpreter but still it keeps giving me this error "No module named PIL" error.
First I thought it was installation issue then I have used multiple ways to add it i.e. adding it via homebrew. But its still not helping. So, what is the ideal way to make it work in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You've got two issues you're going to encounter on this.

1. The "No module name PIL" error implies that PIL is not part of the
   JYTHONPATH.  Assuming you're using PyDev you can add to the path by
   navigating to Preferences->PyDev->Interpreters->Jython Interpreter
   and adding to the PYTHONPATH for the interpreter to include the path
   to PIL.
2. In jython this will only work with pure python packages as jython
   uses JVM and will not be able use CPython packages (typical python)
   that have extensions written in C.  You are going to encounter this problem when you import Image from PIL.

The advantage of jython is that it can work well with existing java libraries so you may want to consider using a library such as ImageJ.  To import and interact with java libraries add the full path to the *.jar file from which you'd like to import as described above for the jython interpreter.

Comment: I have PIL added in the PYTHONPATH and I have tried with with pure python as well but the story remains the same.

Comment: What do you get for the following:  `import sys` then `print sys.path`